# Sort Form fields in sequence

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-access

thanks in advance for your help.

I have a form with spreadsheet view that has 3 fields I want to use to sort: Customer, amount and currency.

When I do the sorting by hand, I sort the amount ascending, the currency A-Z and the customer A-Z following that specific order (the result of sorting fields one by one is a table structure I like because it is easy to read). I do this by clicking the field's header and activating the sort, one field at a time.

I tried to replicate this sequence by adding a macro to the form that runs when the form loads, however it seems like the sort is manipulating the 3 fields at the same time. The result does not look like the one I get when I manually sort one field at a time.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.OrderBy = ""
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Amount DESC, Currency ASC, Customer ASC"

End Sub
```

Is there any way to set fields sorts one after the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Customer ASC, Currency ASC, Amount DESC"`

Comment: Add sample data as text table in question. Your narrative says Amount should be ascending yet you use DESC in code. Why use VBA instead of setting form OrderBy property in design? Or use a query with ORDER BY clause as RecordSource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.OrderBy = "Amount DESC, Currency ASC, Customer ASC"
    Me.OrderByOn = True

End Sub
```